# require "creates 4th partition table" when using Yumi to install centos or manjaro from usb. what should I do?

Tags: usb, partitioning, installation, usb-boot

I using Yumi to install centos or manjaro from usb, after choosing create, a message appears as
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK1gf.png)

How do I know whether 4th partition label already exist or not?

If 4th partition label doesn't exist, is that ok if I accept the require of Yumi to create a 4th partition table?

If 4th partition label exist, is that ok to overwritten it as require of Yumi?

This message does not happen when I use Yumi to install ubuntu, linux mint from usb; and I use Yumi in Windows 7.

Comment: Just to make it clear: the message is confusing, there is no such thing as "4th partition table". In MBR there is one and only partition table. In GPT there are two: primary and secondary (backup). The message should say "4th partition table *entry*", i.e. the 4th entry in the table. Besides Windows (usually) assigns letters to partitions, not to devices, so talking about partitions or partition table(s) on G: is a misuse. But this is probably because most Windows users are familiar with G:, unfamiliar with `\\?\Device\Harddisk1`.

Comment: I have the same issue with the latest legacy YUMI v2.0.6.5. This also happens on Windows 10 64 bit, so I guess it's not because of the Windows version. It must be syslinux and/or BIOS/UEFI related, but I have no proof yet.

Comment: @ydhhat Did you use Rufus before on that USB drive? I did it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution was to **download the latest UEFI version of YUMI** and create the installer USB using that.

At the time of writing, the latest installer was [YUMI-UEFI-0.0.1.5](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-UEFI-0.0.1.5.exe)

It seems that Manjaro has been made for modern UEFI capable hardware.

Please note that the installer threw some syslinux related error messages if I turned off the CSM mode, but it continued the installation process. Nevertheless, I've turned CSM on and the error message didn't show up after restarting the installation this way.

I know that a lot depends on the hardware, please don't follow my advice blindly, do experiment and use the best configuration that you can find.

**Further tips for the installation**

1. enable UEFI-CSM in your BIOS/UEFI
2. disable secure boot in your BIOS/UEFI
3. be careful with non-free drivers during install, it caused the installer to hang after discovering the audio device
4. default user and password is manjaro

Good luck!